# Facing Issue in passing metadata field with DataprocCreateClusterOperator (Airflow 2.0)

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow-2.x

I am facing some issues while installing Packages in the Dataproc cluster using `DataprocCreateClusterOperator`
I am trying to upgrade to Airflow 2.0

Error Message:

```
ValueError: metadata was invalid: [('bigquery-connector-version', '1.1.1'), ('spark-bigquery-connector-version', '0.17.2'), ('PIP_PACKAGES', 'oyaml'), ('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.8.12 grpc/1.39.0 gax/1.31.1 gccl/airflow_v2.1.2+composer')]
```

On further dig down came across a [github link] (https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/19446) , where this issue of `ValueError: metadata was invalid`  is discussed in community forum.

I followed the link and used CLUSTER_CONFIG way to generate the cluster_config for DataprocCreateClusterOperator  but now running into another new issue as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
    details = "Compute Engine instance tag '-' must match pattern (?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1640080533.396337969","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.97.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1069,"grpc_message":"Compute Engine instance tag '-' must match pattern (?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)","grpc_status":3}"
```

I do not see much information around.

Here is the code :

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocCreateClusterOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import ClusterGenerator

CLUSTER_CONFIG = ClusterGenerator(
    project_id="project_id",
    region="us-central1",
    cluster_name="cluster_name",
    tags="dataproc",
    num_workers=2,
    storage_bucket=None,
    num_masters=1,
    master_machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    master_disk_type="pd-standard",
    master_disk_size=1024,
    worker_machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    worker_disk_type="pd-standard",
    worker_disk_size=1024,
    properties={},
    image_version="1.5-ubuntu18",
    autoscaling_policy=None,
    idle_delete_ttl=7200,
    optional_components=['JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA'],
    metadata={"gcs-connector-version" : '2.1.1' , 
                  "bigquery-connector-version": '1.1.1',
                  "spark-bigquery-connector-version": '0.17.2',
                  "PIP_PACKAGES" : 'datalab shap oyaml click apache-airflow apache-airflow-providers-google'
                 },
    init_actions_uris =['gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-{region}/connectors/connectors.sh','gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-{region}/python/pip-install.sh']
).make()

with dag:
   create_dataproc_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="create_test_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name="cluster_name",
        project_id="project_id",
        region="us-central1",
        cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
    )
    
   create_dataproc_cluster
```

Comment: Looks like the error is related to the `tags`. Can you try with `tags=["dataproc"]`? the type should be `List[str]`

Comment: There is also a problem in the cluster name. You can' t use `_` on it. So `cluster_name="cluster_name"` is invalid. Change it to something like `cluster_name="cluster-name"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following dag is working as expected, changed:

- the cluster name (`cluster_name` -> `cluster-name`).
- path for scripts.
- Dag definition.

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import DataprocCreateClusterOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import ClusterGenerator

CLUSTER_CONFIG = ClusterGenerator(
    project_id="project_id",
    region="us-central1",
    cluster_name="cluster-name",
    tags=["dataproc"],
    num_workers=2,
    storage_bucket=None,
    num_masters=1,
    master_machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    master_disk_type="pd-standard",
    master_disk_size=1024,
    worker_machine_type="n1-standard-4",
    worker_disk_type="pd-standard",
    worker_disk_size=1024,
    properties={},
    image_version="1.5-ubuntu18",
    autoscaling_policy=None,
    idle_delete_ttl=7200,
    optional_components=['JUPYTER', 'ANACONDA'],
    metadata={"gcs-connector-version" : '2.1.1' , 
                  "bigquery-connector-version": '1.1.1',
                  "spark-bigquery-connector-version": '0.17.2',
                  "PIP_PACKAGES" : 'datalab shap oyaml click apache-airflow apache-airflow-providers-google'
                 },
    init_actions_uris =['gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-central1/connectors/connectors.sh','gs://goog-dataproc-initialization-actions-us-central1/python/pip-install.sh']
).make()


with models.DAG(
    "example_gcp_dataproc",
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    
   create_dataproc_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="create_test_dataproc_cluster",
        cluster_name="cluster-name",
        project_id="<your-project-name>",
        region="us-central1",
        cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
    )
    
   create_dataproc_cluster
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding cluster_name, I believe its a typo  here but yeah we are aware of the naming convention. Tags was something which was creating the issue as blackbishop has pointed in above comment. The datatype is not string rather List[str]

Comment: Nice, I have edited to add the tags as list, I have forgot that. Thanks